# SOLR index size differing a lot from windows to Linux machine after re-index

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

Currently am running solr 4.5.1 on windows machine. and Am planning to upgrade that one to 5.2.1 simultaneously  moving it from windows to linux. 
Since There are some changes to schema file, after upgrading am re-indexing the data again by querying the data from SOLR server which is hosted on windows machine using SOLRENTITYPROCESS to achieve this. But once the data is re-indexed in New linux machine i see huge difference in index size in WINDOW machine size was shown as 1GB where as the size in Linux machine shown as few MB.  There is no change in the document count. The count is same.

Could  anyone please help in understanding this why there is a huge difference in index size.

Thanks

Comment: Has the index on the existing server been optimized? (meaning; has the index actually been rewritten to expunge deleted documents)

Comment: Yes the Index on the existing server(windows) is optimized. I have manually optimized before loading it to new server(Linux machine).

Comment: Have you issued a hard commit on the new server? (so the updates are not just stored in the transaction log / tlog) How are you determining the size of the index directories?

Comment: Yes i have *autocommit* enabled in the new servers. And am getting the index size from the UI am not manually checking directories to get the size.

Comment: I found the issue it was actually  issue with data what i was trying to re-index. In Old solr i had one field which was not stored instead just indexed, so when i was using solr entity  that data was not  getting re-indexed into the new server.  That  the reason  i saw the difference in index size. Thanks for the help @MatsLindh